# User roles and what they can see

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on how one would approach my scenario.

I have or will have a authentication system that will allow for users roles. So I require a super admin who will be access everything on the web app, admins who can only view their dashboard by id.

So a super admin can login and create dashboards will contain various pieces of information like teams, members and scores. There will be admins who can also create dashboards and view only the dashboards they have created. Super admins can see any dashboard created and users who can only see not create any dashboards but see the dashboards they are associated to by id.

I thought I would pose this question before i even begin to figure it out and see if anyone had any insight on the best approach.

My urls will be like `www.mysite.com/index.php?dashboard_id=1`

If user who are associated with that dashboard by Id they can only see that dashboard and no others, the same applies to admins, however super admins can see any dashboard. Im looking for the cleanest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're  writing  it , or are you using some framework etc.

There is  quite good concept  for your problem implemented in symfony framework, and it's called  voter

Idea is that a single service  decide what to show/allow to edit based on logged user .

Look  at  http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html.

I know that if you don't use  framework, this voter idea  could be too complicated  for you , but idea of it is nice and  clean .

That's the main reason wy peopel learning frameworks, with  framework  you're getting tools  like this "out of the box"  :)

Comment: Thank you and actually thats a very good point and something that I should have included in my question for sure. I am using a custom built authentication system and no framework. I wasn't sure if using perhaps SESSION or GET methods to handle this type of problems.